# PCF component with entity reference

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-crm-365

I am working to implement a PCF-Control in a model based power app.

My goal is to add a “button” (the PCF component) to the right of an existing reference field in my power apps formula in dynamics 365.

The button should add a “flagged status” (Boolean) and update a check mark accordingly.

I have 2 issues.

1. My component cannot render in the same field as my entity reference and I cannot seem to create custom logic to be able to replicate the reference field with an added “flag button”.
   I have seen previous cases of a string being able to be manipulated to be shown/hidden, but cannot find anything about the same for an entity reference.
2. I cannot seem to get the proper id for the ‘incident’ that I want to flag when it is showcased as a reference on another formula. My issue being that I can’t seem to access the ID (CRM guid) for the ‘incident’-entity.
   Even though I mark the entity in the manifest and binding PCF control and entity together upon adding the PCF component to my solution.

Does anyone know if my use case for the PCF-control is valid or if I should look into other solutions?
I am happy to provide some code and or setup samples but for now I don’t know where to start.

I am also happy to start a fruitful discussion regarding use cases for PCF-controls VS ribbons VS custom JavaScript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it model driven app or canvas app?

Comment: It is a model driven app. I am trying to add the PCF component to a "create entity"-formular

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. It won't be possible to add a button to the field. You can create a PCF control and add the button to it but you will have to render the whole control including the input element.

You can start here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/component-framework/overview